# A phrase for something that you enjoy, but is quite bad for you

Tags: phrase-requests, popular-refrains

What is a phrase that describes something that you enjoy that is also quite bad for you? It's usually used when talking about foods that are bad for you.

I used to use it, but for some reason, and it's annoying me, I can't remember it anymore! A similar phrase, not the one I'm looking for, might be "my sweet poison".

Comment: How about "foible" or "vice"?

Comment: a guilty pleasure

Comment: My *forbidden foods*.

Comment: I've heard people say "my personal poison".

Comment: How about making the critics happy and writing an example sentence which will give us(and you)  a clue about the phrase.

Comment: ..........vice?

Comment: A barkeep might ask of a patron to "Name your poison."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - Please make an answer with "guilty pleasure" so that I can upvote it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the word/expression when you take pleasure in doing something that convention says you are not supposed to do?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297837/what-is-the-word-expression-when-you-take-pleasure-in-doing-something-that-conve) Or [a word that means the thrill of doing what is forbidden](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394365/looking-for-a-word-that-means-the-thrill-of-doing-what-is-forbidden/518873#518873)? ...

Comment: Or [how to describe-very tasty and probably unhealthy food](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355274/how-to-describe-very-tasty-and-probably-unhealthy-food/355334#355334)?

Answer (score 3):

**[a guilty pleasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guilty_pleasure)**

> A guilty pleasure is something, such as a film, a television program, a piece of music, or an activity, that one enjoys despite understanding that it is not generally held in high regard, or is seen as unusual or weird.

I have heard it also in connection with food and drink.

Answer (score -1):

The word you are looking for is **Decadent**.
It's definition is:

> [characterized by or appealing to self-indulgence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decadent)

This word is commonly used on chocolate bar wrappers, like this one:
http://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ucm271581.htm

Comment: No, *decadent* need not mean either *is bad for you* or *is something you enjoy*.

Comment: @David Handelman Incorrect, refer to this SE page: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106227/decadence-of-the-word-decadence